# How apply a gamma correction to the RGB values, which makes the color more vivid and more the like the color displayed on the screen of your device?

Tags: c#, objective-c

Searching the internet I found this block of code written in ios objective-C:

```
float red = (red > 0.04045f) ? pow((red + 0.055f) / (1.0f + 0.055f), 2.4f) : (red / 12.92f);
float green = (green > 0.04045f) ? pow((green + 0.055f) / (1.0f + 0.055f), 2.4f) : (green / 12.92f);
float blue = (blue > 0.04045f) ? pow((blue + 0.055f) / (1.0f + 0.055f), 2.4f) : (blue / 12.92f);
```

but I do not know how to convert it to c#

Comment: Hi, best is to start simple: if you want to do bit manipulation: try to get the bits from your image first. If you already got them, show us how your data is stored. There are some question about that subject around on SO.

Comment: the only thing I need is to make those calculations (code above) written in ios, I think it's the solution to my problem. but I'm not able to convert the C-objective to c #

Comment: Have you tried it? Because since the syntax is strongly related you only need to replace `pow` with `Math.Pow`. But you need the input data as well... and it needs to be in the correct format.... so ... I doubt that this is *"the only thing you need*"

Comment: the values ​​of its properties red, green and blue I have them. now I try a change from the code to the pow in Math.Pow

Comment: Okay, I added a working answer, tested in .net fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly.

Comment: For a faster solution you may want to look into ColorMatrix class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your request, the conversion, converted to double in the progress (I tried it in a fiddle to be sure of the syntax):

```
//initialized from image
double red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

double r_output = (red > 0.04045) ? 
                  System.Math.Pow((red + 0.055) / (1.0 + 0.055), 2.4) : 
                  (red / 12.92);
double g_output = (green > 0.04045) ? 
                  System.Math.Pow((green + 0.055) / (1.0 + 0.055), 2.4) : 
                  (green / 12.92);
double b_output = (blue > 0.04045) ? 
                  System.Math.Pow((blue + 0.055) / (1.0 + 0.055), 2.4) : 
                  (blue / 12.92);
```

See [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mLpf5F)

***note:*** some of this can be simplified, like `1.0 + 0.055 = 1.055`.

After you corrected the output values, you probably want to write them back to the image.

Comment: This calculation performs a `sRGB` to `Linear` convertion, where the `Slope` is `1.0` (that's why is represented as `(1.0 + 0.055)`). The OP won't do much with this, using `ARGB` colors.